# Cannot assign to read only property 'displayName' of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am facing a simple issue I am getting the error "Cannot assign to read only property 'displayName' of object" im adding a setting where you can change your display name in the settings page.

```
 function Changename() {
        currentUser.displayName = setUserName
    }
```

I am using firebase for this project, I cant find anywhere to change this read property to read and write in firebase.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your `currentUser` is a reference to a [`User`/`UserInfo` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.userinfo) from Firebase Authentication. In that case [`displayName` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.userinfo.md#userinfodisplayname) is indeed read-only. If you want to change the user's display name, call `updateProfile` as shown in the documentation on [updating the current user's profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile).

Comment: ok so I tried it out and here is my code, 
```
function Changenames() {
        profileupdate(auth.currentUser, {
            displayName: "Jane Q. User"
          })
    }
```
I used some of the example code, when you click the button it should update the name to the string instead it gives me "TypeError: Object(...) is not a function" ???

Comment: The method is called `updateProfile`, not `profileupdate`. Check the last link in my answer for an example both in v8 and v9 syntax (which are quite different).

Comment: yeah I just noticed that this morning, I finally got it to work! sorry for the bother.